Flowcharts or processes as mathematical objects.
I have been looking for a couple of months for a way to formally define flowcharts as mathematical entities, but have not found much.
Since they usually look like graphs, I would expect a definition of the kind "A flowchart is a directed graph $G$ such that..." or maybe something among the lines of "A flowchart is a pair $(\mathscr{C},F)$ where $\mathscr{C}$ is a category such that... and $F:\mathscr{C}\to ...$ is a functor such that...".
Here the main idea I am trying to capture is that of a process in general, though I am aiming for business processes (see BPMN diagrams for example) and achieving to formally study them as mathematical objects.
Do anyone happen to know if such efforts have been made and if so, where one can read about them? Thanks for any related information!

I read once in David Spikav's book "Seven Skecthes in Composisionality" that monoidal categories may have a place in this discussion, through string/wire diagrams, but I am not completely sure if these objects fully capture the essence of flowcharts.

I think your typical flowchart is something like a DFA, with questions as states and answers as inputs.

@BryanCastro The fact flowcharts seem to bear a resemblance to wiring diagrams is suggestive, but the trick would be in the details of what type of category is used for the semantics of the flowchart.  From what I've seen it's usually possible to define the right category, but the answer may be more complex than what you initially suspected.

Seems I have a lot of studying to do!

Chapter 2.§6 of RFC Walters' "Categories and computer science" might be interesting for you. Walters describes a category $\bf Flw$ of flowcharts as the PROP having objects natural numbers $0,1,2\dots$ and where ${\bf Flw}(m,n)$ is the set of functions $f : m\cdot\mathbb R \to n\cdot\mathbb R$, if $m\cdot \mathbb R$ is the sum of $n$ copies of the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers.
He makes a good point that this describes a category of flowcharts in that it can describe piecewise smooth functions on real numbers, so I won't try to reproduce his argument (which is quite intuitive and graphically appealing -there's a lot of string diagrams- and clever, customary with Walters).
Now, since PROPs are monoid objects in a suitable sense, one can argue that a reasonable definition of algebra for a PROP is a monoidal functor out of that PROP, into a "semantics" category $\cal L$ (for example: vector spaces, with the tensor product, pointed topological spaces, with the smash product, etc.). The literature on PROPs and their algebras is quite vast, spanning from algebraic topology/geometry to physics and even categorical logic, so I won't try to introduce this concept either. It also takes a lot of space to do it explicitly, i.e. diagrammatically. A couple of papers that made the theory click in my head are

https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3050
https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14123

Given all this, I would propose the following definition: a flowchart in a monoidal category $(\cal C,\otimes, I)$ is a strong monoidal functor $F : {\bf Flw} \to \cal C$, probably subject to additional assumptions given by your specific problem.

I think "graphically appeasing" should be "graphically appealing" but I didn't fix the typo since I like it.

I meant appealing, yeah :D

Thank you so much!

I was recently referred to a paper on the Category Theory Zulip server:

Errington, Lindsay. "On the semantics of message passing processes." Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science 29 (1999): 50-77.

Having skimmed it I recall section 2 is "Flowcharts as functors."  This refers to

Burstall, Rod M. "An algebraic description of programs with assertions, verification and simulation." Proceedings of ACM conference on Proving assertions about programs. 1972.

as a reference to the idea. To quote the reference:

In [9] Rod Burstall describes how aflowchart can be represented by a functor from a free category to the category of sets and partial functions or more generally sets and relations.

Now, both papers are relatively old, as far as applied category theory papers go, and I'm sure there are newer good references.  I figured I'd drop them here in case it helps.

Everything is useful! Thank you!
